# Laravel Many to Many relationship with BelongsTo and UUIDS on same model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, eloquent-relationship

**How to get Many to Many relationship working with UUIDS and one table has additional belongsTo relationship?**

I have two tables, `users` and `projects`, where a `user can have many projects` and a `project can have many users, where the project belongsTo a user`.

However, my intermediate table gives `error: unique key violation` when the same user exists in the intermediate, despite being assigned to an entirely new project.

**Users**

```
# Migration
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(Str::uuid());
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

# Users Model 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasUuids, HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    // 1-Many
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
}
```

**Project**

```
# Migration
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(Str::uuid());
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreignUuid('user_id');
        });

# Projects Model
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;

class Project extends Model
{
    use HasUuids, HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * The users that belong to the project.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'project_users');
    }

    // Inverse
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Intermediate Table

```
# Migration
        Schema::create('project_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(Str::uuid());
            $table->timestamps();

            # Whether set to using uuid or foreign uuid, both give same error.
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id');
            $table->foreignUuid('project_id');
        });
```

The above code should allow me to create a new user. Create a new project, set a user as the project owner and set them as a user of the project. Then add others to a project as well.

However, as soon as I attach a user to a second project, my intermediate table gives this error: `SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "project_users_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(33a6d0b1-6602-4bc1-8da5-371d23109f22) already exists.`

Which doesn't make sense, because I'm attaching the user to an entirely different project, not the same old one.

```
Test via routes in web.php

# Runs fine the first time with expected behaviour. New project gets created, the project owner is set to the current user and the project adds the current user to the list of project users. 
# The second time it gives the unique key violation error, despite the second time creating a new project. 

Route::get('/', function () {
    // Get first user
    $user = User::all()[0];

    $project = new Project([
        'name' => 'Test Project 1',
    ]);

    // Set the current user to be the owner of the project
    $project->user()->associate($user);
    $project->save();

    // Add existing user to the list of users in that project
    $serverGroup->users()->attach($user);
    $serverGroupUsers = $serverGroup->users;

    return [
        'User' => $user,
        'Server Group' => $serverGroup,
        'Server Group Users' => $serverGroupUsers,
    ];
});
```

## Versions

PHP: 8.1
Laravel 9.19

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the [comments](https://github.com/goldspecdigital/laravel-eloquent-uuid/issues/33) in that github issue, more or less the UUID id doesn't auto-generate like it should. So I think I was trying to insert a row where the uuid was always set to the user's ID. Which is why I got the non-unique uuid error.

Effectively need to manually create a new UUID and set it each time I want to attach a user to the project.

```
    $project->users()->attach($user, [ 'id' => Str::uuid()->toString()]);
```

After that, my `$user->projects` shows all the projects a user has and `$projects->users` shows all the users a project has.

I wish Laravel updated their examples to be UUID first instead of incrementing ids. Or at least had some section on UUIDs for all their eloquent stuff. I hope this helps some other poor soul that needs UUIDS down the line.